# Bootloader Is Unlocked But Yet Recovery Is Not Flashing (Fastboot Failed error)

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, fastboot, bootloader

I Unlocked My Bootloader  And It Is Showing Me In Red Color (Bootloader:Unlocked) But When  I Tried To Flash Recovery It Failed.
recovery is device specific so no problem in recovery.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well, crystal ball says, your device model does not have separate recovery partition